# Machine Learning challenge: technique for collect the coins

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

Suppose that there is a company that own a couple of [vending machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vending_machine) that collect coins. When the coin  safe is full, the machine can not sell any new item. To prevent this, the company must collect the coins before that. But if the company send the technician too early, the company loses money because he made an unnecessary trip. The challenge is to predict the right time to collect coins to minimize the cost of operation.

At each visit (to collect or other operations), a reading of the level of coins in the safe is performed. This data contains historical information regarding the safe filling for each machine.

What is the best ML technique, approach to this problem computationally?

Comment: That is a bit broad. You could create a model for each machine individually, if they differ very much in the filling behavior, or apply a general model for each. Do the machines fill up more linearly? Then you need simply to extrapolate linearly... Also, is this problem including the traveling salesman problem, i.e. minimizing the travel distance for the technician as well?

Comment: I saw this problem in real world and yes, part of it involves TSP problem but I didn't mention to try to simplify the question. The filling behavior is unknown. All we have is a data set with reading counts. I think it's risky to assume that the filling is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the two parts to the problem I see:

**1) vending machine model**

I would probably build a model for each machine using the historic data. Since you said a linear approach is probably not good, you need to think about things that have influence on the filling of a machine, i.e. time related things like week-day dependency, holiday dependency, etc., other influences like the weather maybe? So you need to attach these factors to the historic data to make a good predictive model. Many machine learning techniques can help creating a model and finding real data correlations. Maybe you should create despriptors from your historical data and try to correlate these to the filling state of a machine. PLS can help reducing the descriptor space and find relevant ones. Neuronal Networks are great if you really have no clue about the underlying math of a correlation. Play around with it. But pretty much any machine learning technique should be able to come up with a decent model

**2) money collection**

Model the cost for a random trip of the technician to a machine. Take into account the filling grade of the machines and the cost of the trip. You can send the technician on virtual collecting tours and calculate the total cost of collecting the money and the revenues from the machine. Use again maybe a neuronal network with some evolutionary strategy to find an optimum of trips and times. you can use the model of the filling grade of the machines during the virtual optimization, since you probably need to estimate the filling grade of the machines in these virtual collection rounds.

Interesting problems you have...

Comment: Ok. I agree with you. I thought about using Naïve Bayes classifier to model the filling of a machine. I have access data like, items quantity and their price per machine and the local. Given a set of attributes and a given time the hypothesis is modeled to figure out if the machine is filled or not. The next part is to figure out the day I need to visit the place before it's already too late.
For the money collection I think it's a classical TSP problem so I could apply some technique for this too. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: a Bayes classifier model might work well. Yes, go for it! I think it makes sense to look at both problems separated first. Good luck!